# How to make a button load a function on itself when it is inserted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

At the moment my script is layered out like so...

PHP Echos out button.

Jquery UI button function to apply on the object that the function was called by.

Is there a way to make the button perform MyAddButtonFunction(this) when the button is inserted. (Note there are multiple buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
echo '<input type="button" id="button1" />';
echo '<script>MyAddButtonFunction($("#button1"))</script>'
```

or is this ajaxed in?

Comment: basically yeah, it's sort of like that. But the problem with it is the fact that, the one's on top of it get bigger each time a new button gets inserted.